# errors y old no me funciona en la vista - laravel 7

Tags: laravel-7

Estoy trancado desde hace rato buscando una solución y no la encuentro, por eso acudo a la ayuda de la comunidad, muy agradecido de antemano.

Cómo lo indique, la validación del form pasa porque me redirecciona pero errors no acumula nada, he leído que hay que agregar otros método al redireccionamiento, el detalle es que laravel lo hace automáticamente y según su documentación no hay que hacer más nada sino imprimir los errores en la vista.

Tengo el siguiente **Request**:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        //dd($_REQUEST['ci']);
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'password2' => 'required'
        ];
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Nombre y Apellido',
            'email' => 'Correo Electrónico',
            'password' => 'Contraseña',
            'password2' => 'Repetir contraseña'
        ];
    }

}
```

Parte de la **vista**:

```
{{-- @if ($errors->any()) --}}
<div>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
{{-- @endif --}}

<form method="POST" action="{{ url('api/user') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <label for="ci">Cédula Identidad</label>
    <input type="text" name="ci" id="ci" placeholder="Cédula Identidad" value="{{ old('ci') }}"><br>

    @error('ci')
    <p>{{ $message }}</p>
    @enderror

    <label for="name">Nombre y Apellido</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" value="{{ old('name') }}"><br>

    <label for="phone">Teléfono / Celular</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="" value="{{ old('phone') }}"><br>

    <label for="email">Correo Electrónico</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" value="{{ old('email') }}"><br>
```

El Controlador, método **store**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\UserRequest;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function store(UserRequest $request)
    {
        dd($request);
    }
}
```

Cuando lleno todos los campos de forma correcta se imprime el dd($request), pero si no lo hago buscando que la validación detenga el proceso, laravel lo hace, redirecciona, pero no llegan los errores ni los old a la vista.

[image: Resultado del dd($request) del método store del controlador]

**Los valores como ven se reciben en el controlador e incluso en la clase UserRequest también, porque hice un dd($_REQUEST) dentro del método rules y vi los resultados**

Cómo indique anteriormente yo no estoy haciendo la redirección, la hace laravel y según la documentación según como lo tengo, todo debe funcionar, pero no es así, si logran ver que me hace falta agregar o que estoy haciendo mal les agradezco.

Comment: No le pongas resuelto al título de tu pregunta así no funciona la plataforma, alcanza con que publiques tu solución y la marques como aceptada así los demás nos enteramos ya lo resolviste

Answer (score 0):

**Ya he resuelto el problema**.

Era un tema de rutas, lo explico de la siguiente manera, en el directorio routes, tenemos varios archivos, de los cuáles yo estaba usando dos, web.php y api.php, éste último para usar el prefijo en la rutas de api/

api.php para el controlador

```
Route::post('/user', 'UserController@store');
```

y en web.php para la vista

```
Route::get('/user/create/{id?}', 'UserController@create');
```

Al parecer al estar así no mezcla la respuesta de un tipo de ruta hacia la otra, la **solución** fue pasar la ruta que estaba en api.php a web.php, quedando el último archivo de esta forma:

```
Route::get('/user/create/{id?}', 'UserController@create');
Route::post('/user', 'UserController@store');
```

Obviamente en el action del form de la vista lo tuve que cambiar a **{{ url('user') }}** y listo, funcionó.